# Why doesn't my javascript regexp work with array items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, variables

```
var x = new Array('1','2','3');
var y = new Array('a','b','c');
var iLen = x.length;
var s = 'abcdefgabcdefg';

for (var i=0;i<iLen;i++) {
   var re = new RegExp(x[i],'g');
   s = s.replace(y[i], re);
}

alert(s);
```

I want the result to be **123defg123defg**.
Instead, I get **/1/g/2/g/3/gdefgabcdefg**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, because you want to replace occurrences of array `y` to occurrences of `x` globally,  you should say like

```
for (var i=0;i<iLen;i++) {
   var re = new RegExp(y[i],'g'); //this is regexp for global y[i]
   s = s.replace(re, x[i]); //replace all occurrences of y[i] with x[i]
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Would you believe that, despite scouring the Web for documentation on RegExp, I found nothing that made clear which element goes where? And yet, now that I see your answer, I do understand that it is consistent with the "documentation" elsewhere. Much obliged.